# juego del Ahorcado con clases abstractas

Tags: java

Resulta que debo crear el juego `Ahorcado`, entonces ya apliqué todo el código pero resulta que quiero generar palabras aleatorias, claro que palabras ya definidas y agarrar todo en un arreglo donde con la clase `Math.Random()` poder generar números aleatorios dentro del rango del arreglo y así poder tomar palabras aleatorias para que el juego sea más didáctico. He aquí parte del código que aún no sé manejar clases abstractas, es por ello que pido su ayuda:

```
public abstract class Palabras
{
    private String nombre;
    private String Descripcion;
    public abstract void setNombre(String nombre);
    public abstract void getNombre();
}
public class PlatosTipicos extends Palabras
{
    //...
}
```

Entonces esa es mi duda, no sé como proseguir.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jgGw.png]

Comment: Trabaja un poco más el código porque con lo que tienes parece que lo has intentado poco. Si quieres elegir palabras aleatorias te hace falta un `Random` para generarte números dentro del tamaño de una `List<>` que tampoco tienes donde cargar las palabras que faltan. Para ello no te hace falta usar clases abstractas asi que deberías explciar también para qué quieres usarlas.

Comment: si gracias a sus respuestas pude implementar bien todo gracias en verdad

Comment: @J.zer si alguna respuesta resolvió tus dudas debes marcarla como "respuesta aceptada"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estoy entendiendo mal o lo que queres hacer es heredar de Palabras a otros tipos de palabras?

Si estoy en lo correcto, debo decirte, que no se si vale la pena crear varias clases para diferentes tipos de palabras, podrias usar alguna estructura que te permita guardar varios tipos de cosas, como por ejemplo ArrayList de ArrayList.

Por como hiciste eso parece mas orientado a una interfaz-implentando que a una herencia. Las interfaces son como las clases abstractas pero con la diferencia de que únicamente pones adentro los metodos que obligas a implementar.
ej:

```
public interfaz observable
{
    public void mostrarDatos();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Las clases abstractas sirven para compartir métodos y atributos de una clase superior, y que no debe ser implementable, (no puedes crear un objeto de ella), por ejemplo, tu tienes tu getter y setter en la clase Palabras, por lo que en PlatosTipicos deberás implementar ese setNombre(String nombre) y getNombre() y al hacer esto como el atributo lo tienes en privado, no podrás acceder de el de forma sencilla. (Se puede vía reflect).

Las clases abstractas te permiten abstraer en lo posible tu problema, ahorita tu problema es generar nueva palabra, por lo que yo haría algo así.

```
public abstract class Palabras{ //por favor es Java no C o C# las llaves en Java suelen escribirse en la firma de la clase o método.
   //Podrías hacer que nombre y descripción esten dentro de un constructor.

    public Palabras(String nombre, String descripcion){
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.descripcion=descripcion;
    }

    private String nombre;
    private String Descripcion;
    public void setNombre(String nombre){
         this.nombre=nombre;
    }
    public String getNombre(){
         return nombre;
    }
    public abstract String obtenerPalabra(); 
}
public class PlatosTipicos extends Palabras{
    public String obtenerPalabra(){
    //Tu algoritmo de obtener aleatoriamente la palabra.
    }
}
```

Y ya para la ejecución sería algo así

```
Palabras palabra = new PlatosTipicos("nombre","descripcion");
palabras.obtenerPalabra();
```